# Rails 4 can't find fonts in production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, font-face, production

**Scenario:** I have a Rails 4.0.0 application, deploying with capistrano, which precompiles my assets on my production server.

**Problem:** I'm trying to add a font and use it with @font-face. It works locally, but not in production.

**Error message:** "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) "

My fonts are located in *app/assets/fonts/*

**My relevant files:**

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file yada yada yada...
 *
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'stone_sansregular';
  src: url(font-path('stone_sans_regular-webfont.eot') + "?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
    url(font-path('stone_sans_regular-webfont.woff')) format('woff'),
    url(font-path('stone_sans_regular-webfont.ttf'))  format('truetype'),
    url(font-path('stone_sans_regular-webfont.svg') + "#stone_sansregular") format('svg');
}
```

config/application.rb:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

I have looked for answers in several SO posts and other sources but I can't seem to get it right. Btw, I am not deploying on Heroku. What am I missing? I appreciate your help.

**EDIT:**  In production, I find the fonts where I assume they should be: *my-rails-app/current/public/@assets/fonts*

Comment: Is this the real file extension -> app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss.css ? It should only be .css.scss

Comment: Oh sorry, no it's just .css.scss (edited)

Comment: I wonder, could it have anything to do with the MD5 hash that is added to the file names after compilation? Because in the console it sort of looks like it tries to find the file without that extension, just like when running locally.

Comment: @Majoren ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just recently fixed a similar issue once I realized my `font-awesome.css` file was not actually getting loaded in production. I had to do

```
*= require font-awesome.css
```

instead of

```
@import "font-awsome.css";
```

in my application.css.scss manifest.

Also, as for the MD5 hash that gets added on to file names, I'm not sure if that is an issue or not, but I ended up doing:

```
font-url('fontawesome-webfont.eot');
```

rather than

```
url(font-path('fontawesome-webfont.eot')
```

So if that was even an issue, I'm fairly certain using `font-url` will handle it properly.

Comment: This guy knows what he's talking about!

Comment: `font-url` is no longer available. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets